# How to get the height of a hidden image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, dom

When a div is hidden (`display:none`) the browser will not load the images that are inside it. **Is there a way to tell the browser to load the image?** I need the height and the width of the image to do some pre-processing.

Note: due to some other code, I can't make the div visible. [Check the example here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/KeesCBakker/rAhGF/).
Also a "lazy load" example wouldn't work for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've added some preloading, wrapped it into a function and that does the trick:

```
function getImageDimension(el, onReady) {    
    var src = typeof el.attr === 'function' ? el.attr('src') : el.src !== undefined ? el.src : el;

    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function(){
        if(typeof(onReady) == 'function') {
            onReady({
                width: image.width,
                height: image.height
            });
        }
    };
    image.src = src;
}
```

Can be used as:

```
getImageDimension($('#img1'), function(d){ alert(d.height); });
var url = 'http://urology.jhu.edu/patrickwalsh/photo1.jpg';
getImageDimension(url, function(d){ alert(d.height); });
```

Answer (score 4):

Make the div visible, but position it outside the page with `position: absolute;`.

If your "other code" doesn't let you do this either, create a new image node with the same URL, position it outside the page, wait until it's loaded, read its height and destroy.

Comment: Your first solution doesn't work for me, but the second solution sounds promising. Do you have a code example for me?

Comment: @Kees: No, I don't have a code example at hand, but by writing one you would get a fun exercise in DOM and events!

Answer (score 3):

You could try pre-loading the images using jquery - check out this SO answer:

[Preloading images with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery)

This should pre-load them before you even decide to display them.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is only true for items whose parent is "display:none"

See this article on the matter http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/125

Also, see this example (save as an .html file)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>



<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert($("#target").height());
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="parent" style="display:none;">
    <div id="target" style="height:100px;display:block;">
        a
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this thread.

[Don't load hidden images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818063/dont-load-hidden-images)

Comment: I actually **do** want to load hidden images.