# Is it possible to get the size of an Image that is not displayed on the screen using typescript?

Tags: html, image, angular, typescript

The image that I want to check is in a bootstrap dropdown menu, and I would like to check its size without having to click on the dropdown menu, is it possible or is just a fantasy ?
Thank you !

/*  EDIT  */

Here is a little demo of what I have, and I would like to be able to get the size of the image without having to click on the dropdown menu

`the link:`
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zEVZmr

Comment: why typescript? I'd first try to figure out how to do this with basic javascript/jquery. Not sure how would typescript help you out with DOM manipulation

Comment: I am working with angular, that is why I asked for a solution in typescript, but javascript is fine as well

Comment: could you give us some code snippet so we can help you out better?

Comment: You should include the code in the body of your question. Stack Overflow has a Stack Snippet feature precisely for that. I've looked at your codepen and all I see is a black triangle that shows a "build passing" image when clicked. Is that the image you're talking about?

Comment: yes it is, it is a bootstrap dropdown menu, and the image is the "build passing" image I am talking about

Comment: Preload the image: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4852492/881032

Comment: is this the real life