# Run function defined as VAR

Tags: jquery

I ran into [Don't load hidden images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818063/dont-load-hidden-images?answertab=votes#tab-top) ... and wanted to run the function `reveal`.

```
$(function () {
       $("img").not(":visible").each(function () {
           $(this).data("src", this.src);
           this.src = "";
       });

       var reveal = function (selector) {
           console.log("Viser billeder");
           var img = $(selector);
           img[0].src = img.data("src");
       }
    });
```

But how?

If I do this:

```
reveal();
```

It returns this in the console:

```
reveal is not defined
```

How should I call this?

Comment: don't you call it from global context since your variable is of local scope?

Comment: I edited my answer after seeing your jsfiddle. Please take a look :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define reveal in the global scope like this, it should work fine.

```
var reveal;

$(function () {
       $("img").not(":visible").each(function () {
           $(this).data("src", this.src);
           this.src = "";
       });

       reveal = function (selector) {
           console.log("Viser billeder");
           var img = $(selector);
           img[0].src = img.data("src");
       }
    });
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. Calling the `reveal();` still gives me the same error in console.

Comment: I want to call the function, when a tab is shown. That's why I need to call it.

Comment: There are couple of issue in your fiddle. I fixed it, take a look http://jsfiddle.net/DgL7a/1/

Comment: You had defined `reveal` in the outer scope but again specified` var reveal` inside the function.

Comment: There is still a problem: img[0].src = img.data("src");  - do you know why?

Comment: You need to pass some `selector` to reveal function because it take a `selector` param and do `$(selector)`. I have modied the fiddle take a look, hope this makes you understand your mistakes. Take a look http://jsfiddle.net/DgL7a/2/

Comment: @Kenneth - Did you get a chance to take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/DgL7a/2/ ?

Answer (score 1):

`reveal` will only be defined after:

```
   var reveal = function (selector) {
       console.log("Viser billeder");
       var img = $(selector);
       img[0].src = img.data("src");
   }
```

And before the `});` on the next line, since it is private to the anonymous function.

**Edit**

After looking at the code from your jsfiddle, you have another error. First of all the reason it's still not working is because after you took @ShankarSangoll's advice and added   `var reveal` in the outer scope, you kept the `var` keyword in the inner scope as well so now you just have two variables named `reveal`, the outer one is still undefined. If you remove `var` from the inner one it will be defined.

However you have a `$(function(){ ...});` inside a `$(document).ready(function(){ ...};` which is redundant since you know the document is already ready inside your ready function. YOu can change your code to:

```
$(function() {
    var reveal;
    console.log("Billeder vises");
    $("img").not(":visible").each(function() {
        $(this).data("src", this.src);
        this.src = "";
    });

    var reveal = function(selector) {
        var img = $(selector);
        img[0].src = img.data("src");
    }

    reveal();
});
```

Or remove the `$(function(){ ...});` wrapper altogether since that delays your scripts. You'll also want to pass a selector to `reveal()`, but I think you know that :)

Comment: I need to call the function reveal, when the user clicks on some tabs. How do I call it??

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the variable outside of its scope. The var/function (reveal) is defined INSIDE of a parent function ( $(function(){... ), so it can only be used INSIDE of that parent function since it is LOCAL to it (just like any other local variable you define).